# Making a family of graphs in TikZ by a few definitions

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am trying to make in TikZ a family of graphs, as in included pictures. I can make them one by one, using nodes (circle/square/triangle, black/white) and joining them. However it seems to me, that all the graphs are so similar, then, lest us say, three definitions could define all of them.

I am still a beginner in TikZ, so I have not a good idea, how such definitions may look like.

**Edit** (transferred from comments):
I think, for example, that first three graphs from Fig. 1 could be obtained by concatenating graphs from Fig. 2, with their parameters changed. Is it a valuable idea of simplifying my work, or not?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I do no expect someone doing it for me, but a few valuable suggestions, e.g.: can first three graphs from Fig. 1 be obtained by concatenating graphs from Fig. 2, with their parameters changed?

Comment: Yes this _can_ be done. But given this many options it is difficult to help you. Why not provide just 2 graphs and come up with strategies to do that an go from there? One way would be to create a single figure that has _all_ the possible connections that might be required and then define a style for each edge based on if you want that edge drawn or not. You can also define a style for each vertex to determine its shape.  Also, it may actually be more work to reuse one `tikzpicture` as opposed to having different `tikzpictures` for each figure.

Comment: Off-topic: Which category of graphs are they ? Bond-graphs ? Just to know the name of graphs and its domain.

Comment: @texenthusiast I don't know. I was asked by my friend working in the graph theory to help him. Hence I am trying to make the graphs in an elegant way.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: It would be helpful if you included a MWE that shows how 1 of the diagrams is drawn with `tikz`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a 'please do this complex thing' for me question with no code showing attempts by the OP. 