# Strange connection of nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

This question is in connection with [Making a family of graphs in TikZ by a few definitions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110756/making-a-family-of-graphs-in-tikz-by-a-few-definitions).

In the following MBWE lines in the first diamond, that were expected to be vertical, have unexpected angles. What should I know to correct this behaviour?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[inner sep=0.7mm,
koc/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=black,thick,minimum size=3mm},
kob/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=white,thick,minimum size=3mm},
kwc/.style={rectangle,draw=black,fill=black,thick,minimum size=3mm},
kwb/.style={rectangle,draw=black,fill=white,thick,minimum size=3mm},
trc/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,draw=black,fill=black,thick, minimum size=1mm},
empty/.style={},
trb/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,draw=black,fill=white,thick,minimum size=1mm}]

\node[trc] (A)[label=above:$a$] {};
\node[kob] (D) [above right=of A] {};
\node[empty](empty)[right=of A]{};
\node[kwb] (F) [below right=of  A] {};
\begin{scope}[on grid,node distance=9mm]
\node[kwc] (B) [below=of D,label=above left:$b$] {};
\node[kob] (E) [above=of F] {};
%\node[trc] (F) [below right=of  A] {f};
\end{scope}
\node[trc](C)[right=of empty,label= above:$c$]{};

\foreach \k in {D,B,E,F} \draw(A)--(\k); 
\foreach \k in {D,B,E,F}\draw (\k)--(C);
\draw (D)--(B);
\draw (B)--(E);
\draw (E)--(F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[inner sep=0.7mm,
koc/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=black,thick,minimum size=3mm},
kob/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=white,thick,minimum size=3mm},
kwc/.style={rectangle,draw=black,fill=black,thick,minimum size=3mm},
kwb/.style={rectangle,draw=black,fill=white,thick,minimum size=3mm},
trc/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,draw=black,fill=black,thick, minimum size=1mm},
empty/.style={},
trb/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,draw=black,fill=white,thick,minimum size=1mm}]

\node[kwb] (A) {};
\node[kob] (D) [above right=of A] {};
\node[empty](empty)[right=of A]{};
\node[kob] (F) [below right=of  A] {};
\begin{scope}[on grid,node distance=8mm]
\node[trc] (B) [right=of A,label=above right:$a$] {};
\node[kwc] (E) [left=of C,label=above right:$b$] {};
\end{scope}
\node[trc](C)[right=of empty,label=above right:$c$]{};

\foreach \k in {A,B,E,C} \draw(D)--(\k); 
\foreach \k in {A,B,E,C}\draw (\k)--(F);
\draw (A)--(B);
\draw (B)--(E);
\draw (E)--(C);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Case $(\beta,2)$ of Lemma 2.2}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A hint make the upper circle rectangle ;)

Comment: @percusse I am afraid that it is not a hint for me. I have noticed that different object give different results, but I cannot see any regularity.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke The `[above|below] [left|right]=… of somenode` styles automatically set the reference to `somenode.[north|south] [east|west]`. While the circles and rectangles have the same dimensions (`3mm` in width and height), the compass direction `south east` and so on lie on the circles border and not in the corner of a rectangle enclosing that circle (in TikZ syntax, that would be: `(somenode.south -| somenode.east)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a different take, using a `diamond` shape for the four outer nodes, and a path for the two inner nodes. It may be preferable to use either

- `outer sep=+0pt` for every node,
- `line cap=rect` for the lines, and/or
- a `draw`n diamond

so that the lines do not awkwardly end at the nodes’ borders (which is only visible for high zoom levels).

I took the liberty to re-organize the styles.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every whateverthisis/.style={thick, draw=black, inner sep=+0.7mm},
  circle style/.style=  {shape=circle,                                   minimum size=+3mm},
  rect style/.style=    {shape=rectangle,                                minimum size=+3mm},
  triangle style/.style={shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, minimum size=+1mm},
  black style/.style={fill=black},
  white style/.style={          },
  koc/.style={every whateverthisis, circle style,   black style},
  kob/.style={every whateverthisis, circle style,   white style},
  kwc/.style={every whateverthisis, rect style,     black style},
  kwb/.style={every whateverthisis, rect style,     white style},
  trc/.style={every whateverthisis, triangle style, black style},
  trb/.style={every whateverthisis, triangle style, white style},
]

\node[shape=diamond, minimum size=2.5cm, outer sep=+0pt] (d) {};

\node[trc, label=above:$a$] at (d.west)  (A) {};
\node[trc, label=above:$c$] at (d.east)  (C) {};
\node[kob]                  at (d.north) (D) {};
\node[kwb]                  at (d.south) (F) {};
\path (d.north) -- (d.south) node [pos=.4, kwc, label=above left:$b$] (B) {}
                             node [pos=.6, kob]                       (E) {};

\draw (A) -- (D) -- (C) -- (F) -- (A);
\path (B) edge (A) edge (C) edge (D) edge (E)
      (E) edge (A) edge (C) edge (F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 7):

One easy way to prevent the problem is to use the `on grid` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[inner sep=0.7mm,
koc/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=black,thick,minimum size=3mm},
kob/.style={koc,fill=white},
kwc/.style={rectangle,draw=black,fill=black,thick,minimum size=3mm},
kwb/.style={kwc,fill=white},
trc/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,draw=black,fill=black,thick, minimum size=1mm},
empty/.style={},
trb/.style={trc,fill=white},on grid,node distance=12mm and 12mm]

\node[trc] (A)[label=above:$a$] {};
\node[kob] (D) [above right=of A] {};
\node[empty](empty)[right=of A]{};
\node[kwb] (F) [below right=of  A] {};
\begin{scope}[on grid,node distance=9mm]
\node[kwc] (B) [below=26pt of D,label=above left:$b$] {};
\node[kob] (E) [above=26pt of F] {};
%\node[trc] (F) [below right=of  A] {f};
\end{scope}
\node[trc](C)[right=of empty,label= above:$c$]{};

\foreach \k in {D,B,E,F} \draw(A)--(\k); 
\foreach \k in {D,B,E,F}\draw (\k)--(C);
\draw (D)--(B);
\draw (B)--(E);
\draw (E)--(F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Case $(\beta,2)$ of Lemma 2.2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]